# Locate Vertical Position of the end of a Paragraph

Tags: vba, ms-word, position, paragraph

I'm trying to insert a vertical line on the left hand side of a paragraph that has been selected.  I can easily find the vertical position of the start of the paragraph using ".Information(wdVerticalpositionRelativeToPage)", the problem is finding how long to make the line.  The only approach I have come up with so far is to find the start of the next paragraph, but is there a more elegant way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Paragraphs can have borders so just switch on the border at the lhs of the paragraph.

Comment: That's was my first solution, unfortunately if the paragraph is actually a table it doesn't work so well!

Comment: The etiquette for stackoverflow is that you are supposed to include in your question a summary of things you have tried which did not work.  Please read the SO help on how to ask a good question.

Comment: OK, Thanks freeflow - lesson learnt!  I've tried Borders and looking for the position of the next paragraph.